# React Native how to create a delete button that deletes a different element as well as itself

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Look at my code below please I am trying to find a way to make a delete button but i am very new to react native, i have been trying to do it for the past few hours.

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, View, Image, TextInput, Button, Keyboard, TouchableOpacity, CheckBox } from 'react-native';
import Interactable from 'react-native-interactable';
export default function App() 
  const [enteredGoal, setEnteredGoal] = useState('');
  const [courseGoals, setCourseGoals] = useState([]);
const goalInputHandler = (enteredText) => {
  setEnteredGoal(enteredText);
};
 const addGoalHandler = () => {
if (enteredGoal.length > 0) {
  setCourseGoals(currentGoals => [...currentGoals, enteredGoal])
} else {
  alert("You have to write something!")
}
}

return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.topPart}></View>
  <View style={styles.navBar}>
    <Image source={require('./assets/baseline_menu_black_18dp.png/')} />
    <Text style={styles.heading}> Grocery List </Text>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.body}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.textInput}
      placeholder='Groceries'
      maxLength={20}
      onBlur={Keyboard.dismiss}
      value={enteredGoal}
      onChangeText={goalInputHandler}
    />

    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.saveButton}>
        <Button title="ADD" onPress={addGoalHandler} color="#FFFFFF" style={styles.saveButtonText} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList

          data={courseGoals}
          renderItem={itemData => (
            <View style={styles.groceryItem} >
              <Text style={styles.groceryItemText}>{itemData.item}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.groceryItemDelete}>X</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
  </View>
</View>

);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,

  },
  topPart: {
    height: '3%',
    backgroundColor: '#5498A7',
  },
  navBar: {
    height: '10%',
    backgroundColor: '#5498A7',
    elevation: 3,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',

  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: '#edebe9',
    height: '100%',
    flex: 1
  },
  heading: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingLeft: '13%',
    fontSize: 25,
    color: '#d6d4d3'
  },
  textInput: {
    borderColor: '#CCCCCC',
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    height: 50,
    fontSize: 25,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20
  },
  saveButton: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#5498A7',
    backgroundColor: '#5498A7',
    padding: 15,
    margin: 5,
  },
  saveButtonText: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  groceryItem: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    backgroundColor: '#6A686B',
    padding: 15,
    margin: 5,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  groceryItemText: {
    color: '#d6d4d3',

  },
  groceryItemDelete: {
    color: 'red',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20
  }
});
```

I hope you guys can find a solution I will keep u guys updated on my progress, I am constantly looking for answers but i don't really understand how to make the delete (X) work and to make it delete a different element, if you know a way to make work better just let me know i would appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the delete method and add an onPress event:

```
renderItem={(itemData, idx) => (
            <View style={styles.groceryItem} >
              <Text style={styles.groceryItemText}>{itemData.item}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.groceryItemDelete} onPress={() => deleteItem(idx)}>X</Text>
            </View>
          )}

const deleteItem = idx => {
    const clonedGoals = [...courseGoals]
    clonedGoals.splice(idx, 1)
    setCourseGoals(clonedGoals)
}
```

Comment: When i tried this it said it "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: courseGoal. I tried renaming it to courseGoals, it had no error but it also did absolutely nothing.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I've updated the answer. Let me know if that helped.